# R.java's values not recognized

Tags: android, r.java-file

I downloaded a an android project folder from a friend (the app works).  In eclipse, I created a new Android project from existing code.  However, there are errors at the lines calling the layouts/ids from R.java.  Example: R.layout.my_layout

I tried cleaning the project, and deleting the project and creating it again.  The code should be working.  I checked R.java to make the sure the name matches.  Note that I am an advanced-beginner at Android, so I know the basics.  Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. if you downloaded the project from a friend, you shouldn't be creating a completely new project, but choose "new project from existing source".
2. try looking in the project properties under Android, many times, the import screws up the properties and moves the target SDK to the lowest possible and you'll need to change that"

Answer (score 2):

it sounds stupid- but try clearing you project, make a simple change in code, save and rebuild.
i hope that'll fix your problem,

another thing- make sure u didnt imported any android.R.###  class - if u did erase those lines.

Wops.

Answer (score 1):

What errors are you getting in console from eclipse?  Error messages are usually need to help.  My only suggestion without seeing the build errors is to check your import statements.  Sometimes eclipse inserts bogus import to the R classes.